# Model bounded proportion data in a repeated measures design

Tags: r, mixed-model, beta-regression

I'm modeling the amount of organic content in bird bones (a percentage) in two different conditions and also over two time periods. The design is repeated measures - observations in both conditions and time periods come from the same bone (divided into pieces). I want to test the hypotheses: 1) there is no difference in E(Y) across conditions, 2) there is no difference in E(Y) across time, 3) there is no difference in difference of E(Y) (i.e., time*condition interaction). I've tried the following (here with dummy data):

```
set.seed(6753)
dat <- data.frame(
    id = rep(1:15, each = 4),
    pc.organic = rnorm(60, 0.11, 0.055),
    condition = factor(rep(c("raw", "advanced"), times = 30)),
    year = factor(rep(c(1, 1, 2, 2), times = 15))
    )

library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(pc.organic ~ condition * year + (1 | id), data = dat)
summary(fm1)
```

This, I think, is an appropriate model to account for the non-independence of observations in the repeated measures design. I'm unsure, however, whether this is ok given the nature of the response variable. The response varies between about .01 (1%) and .2 (20%). It is bounded at zero (obviously), but also at 40% (this is the maximum amount of organic content in any bone - 60% is inorganic). Another option would be to use 40% as the denominator when I define the percentage, thus, the previous values would be .025 and .5 respectively. However, this would still leave the response bounded between 0 and 1.

I've read about beta regression and also about using a logit transformation to linearize the data. If possible, I'd  like to avoid going down these paths, as other researchers in my field are not familiar with these methods. Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Your question contains the seeds of an answer. Calculate the fraction of values that are impossibly negative with a normal distribution with stated mean and SD. I'd recommend biting the bullet and using logit as a link function (not transformation) to avoid impossible predictions http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0147 gives a concise review, but you would need to identify R equivalents. That way you have scope for an innovative paper to show the way to your field. Note that dividing by 0.4 would make the problem that models might predict impossible values worse, not better.